# How to create Map[K, V] and Seq[A] by parsing CSV file?

Tags: scala, csv, scala-collections

I very new to scala, i want to create Scala `Map()` and Scala `Seq()` by parsing csv files.

```
Input1.csv
-------------
State,Capital,Filter,Unique
MH,Mumbai,1,Yes
KA,Bengaluru,0,Yes
AP,Hydrabad,1,No
TS,Hydrabad,1,No
```

from Input1.csv file i want `scala.collection.Map[K, V]`

```
Map("MH" -> "Mumbai", "KA" -> "Bengaluru", "AP" -> "Hydrabad", "TS" -> "Hydrabad")
```

```
Input2.csv
-----------
Columns_Names
State
Capital
Filter
Unique
```

from Input2.csv file i want `scala.collection.Seq[A]`

```
Seq("State", "Capital", "Filter", "Unique")
```

How this can be done in scala?

Comment: What have you tried? What problems do you have?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I am not able to do this in Scala as i am very new to this language.

Comment: All you need is *read from file line by line* and `split` each line using ",". After you will get sequence of `String` array, you will need to get first two elements from each array and create map in the end. For sequence you needed just get first element.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it something like:

```
import scala.io.Source
import scala.util.{Failure, Success, Try}
val source = Source.fromFile("Input1.csv")
val cityMap = Try(source
  .getLines()
  .toSeq
  .tail
  .map {
    x =>
      x.split(",") match {
        case Array(code, capital, _, _) =>
          code -> capital
      }
  }.toMap) match {
  case Failure(exception) =>
    exception.printStackTrace()
    Map.empty[String, String]
  case Success(value) =>
    value
}
println(cityMap) // Map(MH -> Mumbai, KA -> Bengaluru, AP -> Hydrabad, TS -> Hydrabad)
source.close()
```